# ¿Están los "que" bien usado en esta cita de Napoleón?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, sintaxis, conjunciones, subordinadas

Hoy he encontrado una cita de Napoleón que dice:

> Entre aquellos **que** no les gusta la opresión hay muchos **que** les gusta oprimir.
>
> fuente: [brainyquote](https://www.brainyquote.com/es/citas/napoleon-bonaparte_383308)

Ese uso de los "que" me suena un poco raro. Yo habría dicho

> Entre aquellos **a los que** no les gusta la opresión hay muchos **a los que** les gusta oprimir.

o mejor

> Entre aquellos **a quienes** no les gusta la opresión hay muchos **a quienes** les gusta oprimir.

incluso aceptaría

> Entre aquellos **que** no gustan de la opresión hay muchos **que** gustan de oprimir.

Pero esa primera versión con el uso de "que" junto con el pronombre "les" me resulta muy raro.

¿Es válida esa primera forma y si es así, qué tipo de `que` tenemos ahí?

Comment: También, siendo *a* una preposición corta, se admitiría *a que* en vez de *a los que*.  Pero *que* tal cual me suena rarísimo también.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El uso de "que" en esta oración:

> Entre aquellos **que** no les gusta la opresión hay muchos **que** les gusta oprimir.

es anómalo. Se trata de un caso de "queísmo relativo" o "despronominalización del relativo", por cuanto en lugar de mantener su función pronominal "que" queda reducido a un mero nexo. La función pronominal es asumida por un pronombre personal que aparece dentro de la relativa (en este caso, el complemento indirecto "les"), cuando lo habitual sería su duplicación:

- La opresión no **les** gusta **a ellos**.
- **Les** gusta oprimir **a ellos**.

Este fenómeno de convertir al relativo "que" en un simple conector, bastante habitual en la lengua oral, debe evitarse en la lengua escrita, donde "que" debe ser precedido por la preposición que le corresponda según su función dentro de la proposición relativa.

En la oración en cuestión, "que" debe ser "a los que" (o "a quienes") puesto que el complemento indirecto requiere la preposición "a".

Answer (score 3):

Ambos *que* están mal usados. El antecedente de ambas subordinadas, que es el pronombre *aquellos* del comienzo, es sintácticamente el objeto indirecto de *gustar*, de manera que debería estar marcado con la preposición *a*; más allá de eso, como señala OP, se podría usar *los que* o *quienes*. Así como está, *que* estaría funcionando como un sujeto, pero el sujeto es *la opresión* en la primera cláusula y *oprimir* en la segunda. La transformación gramatical es levemente distinta en cada caso porque la primera parte habla de un conjunto definido de personas y la segunda es una cláusula de existencia, pero es un detalle que no cambia el punto principal:

> ***a ellos** no les gusta la opresión*
> → ***a los que** no les gusta la opresión*
>
> *a muchos les gusta oprimir*
> → *hay **muchos a los que** les gusta oprimir*

No sé otros lugares, pero en el uso coloquial rioplatense esta forma es tan habitual que ya casi se diría que es la norma. Curiosamente no está incluido entre los usos poco cuidados ni los errores habituales que menciona [el DPD en su artículo sobre el pronombre relativo *que*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW). Una cosa que sí dice el DPD es que en ciertas partes es común introducir en el subordinada un pronombre átono redundante, con el mismo referente que el relativo...

> *«Es una cosa que **la** puedo compartir»* (← *que puedo*)

...y que esto provoca a su vez, a veces, que se suprima la preposición que indica la función del relativo:

> *«El hermano de tu amiga, que **lo** conocí ayer...»* (← *al que conocí*)

Al decir *aquellos que les gusta* se está, justamente, suprimiendo la preposición *a* que debería preceder al pronombre relativo, quizá porque el pronombre dativo *les* en el interior de la subordinada ya es indicación suficiente de la función de objeto indirecto. Este *les* es redundante pero, a diferencia de los casos ejemplificados por el DPD, es gramatical, ya que el castellano exige repetir el objeto indirecto como pronombre átono en esta estructura (por eso *a ellos gusta* está mal y debemos decir *a ellos les gusta*).